# VLookup Letter Number Values - Delete Rows

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm really struggling with a VLookup situation right now. I'm trying to do something that is really over my head, but I think that with a little help I just might be able to do it.

1. For starters, I created a separate sheet with a table so I can give a number to some letters so I may quantify their value.

[image: Letter Tables]

2. With this information, I would like to elaborate a VBA formula that would be able to check a table for those letter in a column (with a number) and delete every row that would present a letter value lower than the inputed Letter's given number. (Ignore the Ns in column I)

[image: Letter Tables 2]]

3. What I have so far is something like this:

   ```
   Sub DeletarIndices()

       indice = InputBox("Digite o IC/IV Desejado", "GBG Pneus")

       Set planilhaV = Sheets("IV")
       Dim vValores As String
       sResult = Application.VLookup("Y", planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2)

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       Dim i As Long
       For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
           If Not (Range("A" & i).Value > sResult) Then
               Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
           End If
       Next i
       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
   ```

What happens is that when I run the code, a inputbox opens and asks for a value that will be used in the code. The letter will be converted in to a number and will be used as a comparison to delete lower values. But...
Right here:

```
If Not (Range("A" & i).Value > sResult) Then
```

The letter is still a number, so when it checks the table, only numbers lower than the value will be deleted, not the letters with lower values. What I need is exactly that. That letters get analyzed and the rows deleted, not numbers.

Thank you to anyone that may help me with this!

Comment: The user inputs a number, correct? `indice` is to be a number?  You don't use `indice` later in the code that I can see. What do you expect to do with it?  It's unclear though, as you say "The letter will be converted into a number...", so does the user actually insert a letter?

Comment: I'm sorry, `indice` should have been used where I have a `"Y"` in the first `sResult` part.

Comment: Yes, the user should insert a letter.To clarify what needs to happen I may say that these letters are a Index for speed. I need to be able to quantify them and delete unnecessary indexes from my table.

Comment: And `sResult` is a letter, or number that's returned? If it's a Letter, how do you know what number to turn it in to?

Comment: As I said, it is a letter that is turned into a number by VLookup so I may quantify and compare with other values. However, its clearly not working. What I need is any ideas to make that work. ^^

Comment: Sorry - final (hopefully) clarification - `sResult` *should* be a number, but it's still returning a letter?  So, when you try to see if `Range("A" & i)`'s value is greater than `sResult`, you're getting an error, because `sResult` is a letter? I'd first add `Dim sResult as Long` at the beginning, to make sure it gets set as a number, not string or something.

Comment: Ok, I see why you're confused. I'll try to be as clear as possible right now! Haha... -- `indice` will be input as a Letter -- with the VLookup will be transformed into a number. -- It will be compared with numbers in -- `If Not (Range("A" & i).Value > sResult)`. -- What I really want is to have it be compared with Letters. I need a creative way to make the table compare with Letters and delete the ones with lower values as given in the first table image. -- EXAMPLE: If I input a "T", {B, D E, R, S} would be deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134994/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-leonvfx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got some help in a forum, I got to this answer, and I'll leave it here if anyone run into something like this.

```
' Verifies if the digit is a number. If it is, returns True, False if it isn't.
Function ehNumero(ByVal digito As String) As Boolean

    a = Asc(digito)
    If a >= 48 And a <= 57 Then
        ehNumero = True
    Else
        enNumero = False
    End If

End Function

' Separates the code in a numeric and a alphabetic part.
Function separaCodigo(ByVal codigo As String, ByRef numero As Integer, ByRef letras As String) As Boolean
    p = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(codigo)
        digito = Mid(codigo, i, 1)
        If Not ehNumero(digito) Then ' Found the point break when it finds the first non-numeric digit.
            p = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If p = 0 Or p = 1 Then
        numero = 0
        letras = ""
        separaCodigo = False
    Else
        codigo = UCase(codigo)
        numero = Int(Mid(codigo, 1, p - 1))
        letras = Mid(codigo, p)
        separaCodigo = True
    End If
End Function

' Gets the values from the configuration table.
Function valorDasLetras(ByVal letras As String) As Integer
    On Error GoTo trataErro

    valorDasLetras = Application.VLookup(letras, Worksheets("Configuração").Range("A2:B11"), 2, False)

    Exit Function

trataErro:
    valorDasLetras = 0 '

End Function

'Deletes the lines in the table in the interval.
Function deletar(ByVal numero As Integer, letras As String) As Integer

    valor = valorDasLetras(letras)
    If valor = 0 Then
        deletar = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    limInf = numero
    limSup = valor

    Dim dados As Worksheet
    Set dados = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim linhasPraDeletar As Range
    totalLinhas = 0

    linha = 1
    Do While True

        curCodigo = dados.Cells(linha, 7) ' Using Column G

        If curCodigo = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        Dim curNumero As Integer
        Dim curLetras As String
        If Not separaCodigo(curCodigo, curNumero, curLetras) Then
            deletar = -1
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Gets the values for the letters from the table
        curValor = valorDasLetras(curLetras)
        If curValor = 0 Then
            deletar = -1
            Exit Function
        End If

        If curNumero < limInf Or curValor < limSup Then
            If linhasPraDeletar Is Nothing Then
                Set linhasPraDeletar = dados.Rows(linha)
            Else
                Set linhasPraDeletar = Union(linhasPraDeletar, dados.Rows(linha))
            End If
            totalLinhas = totalLinhas + 1
        End If

        linha = linha + 1
    Loop

    linhasPraDeletar.Select
    linhasPraDeletar.EntireRow.Delete ' <===== Comment to select, but do not delete, the line

    deletar = totalLinhas

End Function

' Run the code
Sub LimparValores()
    'On Error GoTo trataErro

    ' Reads the user code
    msg = "Input your code"
    codigo = InputBox(msg, "Código")
    If codigo = "" Then ' Cancelado
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Separates the user code number from letters
    Dim numero As Integer
    Dim letras As String
    If Not separaCodigo(codigo, numero, letras) Then
        MsgBox ("Invalid code: " & codigo)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Calls the delete function
    linhas = deletar(numero, letras)
    If linhas = -1 Then
        MsgBox ("There was an error with the code (the letter does not exist in configuration)")
    Else
        If linhas = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("There are no rows in the interval - no row was deleted")
        Else
            MsgBox (linhas & " rows deleted!")
        End If
    End If

    Exit Sub

trataErro:
    MsgBox ("The code is not in the expected format.")

End Sub
```

Hope it helps anyone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your order of priority for the letters is always alphabetical, you don't need to convert letters to numbers for this, you can simply compare letter to letter.  I would also note that your way to determine the last row (`Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`) is not good practice, I suggest you find a more reliable method.

Assuming your data is presented as you have shown - with data in column H as a 3-character code where the letter is the last character (e.g. "91B", "89D", etc.) - lets go through step by step: (note there is no lookup worksheet planilhaV any more)

1) Declare our variables

```
Dim indice As String   ' To hold our user input letter
Dim rowLetter As String   ' To hold the current row letter value
Dim firstRow As Long   ' First row of your data
Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last row of your data
Dim currentRow As Long   ' Current row for your loop counter
Dim sht As Worksheet   ' To hold the worksheet you're working on
```

2) Assign some values

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("*WORKSHEET NAME*")   ' Use the name of your worksheet
firstRow = 1
lastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

3) Get your user input

```
indice = UCase(InputBox("Digite o IC/IV Desejado", "GBG Pneus"))   ' Convert user input to upper case and store
```

4) Do your processing

```
For currentRow = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
    rowLetter = UCase(Right(sht.Range("H" & currentRow).Value, 1))   ' Get letter from code in column H, converted to upper case
    If rowLetter < indice Then   ' Compare the letters, and if smaller than user input...
        sht.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete   ' Delete the row
    End If
Next currentRow
```

And that should about do it.  It's a good idea to declare all variables you plan to use, and using `Option Explicit` will ensure you can't use anything without declaring it first.

**EDIT:**

@LeonVFX: If the value of the letters doesn't always increase with alphabetical order then you could use a lookup table or you could do the comparison in code.

If you choose to use a lookup table like in your original example, then you could adjust the code above as follows:

```
Dim indice As String   ' To hold our user input letter
Dim indiceValue As Long   ' To hold the numeric value of our user input letter
Dim rowLetter As String   ' To hold the current row letter
Dim rowLetterValue As Long   ' To hold the numeric value of the current row letter
Dim firstRow As Long   ' First row of your data
Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last row of your data
Dim currentRow As Long   ' Current row for your loop counter
Dim sht As Worksheet   ' To hold the worksheet you're working on
Dim planilhaV As Worksheet   ' To hold your lookup worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("*WORKSHEET NAME*")   ' Use the name of your worksheet
Set planilhaV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IV")   ' As in your original example
firstRow = 1
lastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

indice = UCase(InputBox("Digite o IC/IV Desejado", "GBG Pneus"))   ' Convert user input to upper case and store
indiceValue = CLng(Application.VLookup(indice, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2, False))   ' Creating numeric indice value with lookup table

For currentRow = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
    rowLetter = UCase(Right(sht.Range("H" & currentRow).Value, 1))   ' Get letter from code in column H, converted to upper case
    rowLetterValue = CLng(Application.VLookup(rowLetter, planilhaV.Range("A2:B11"), 2, False))   ' Creating numeric value for current row letter with lookup table
    If rowLetterValue < indiceValue Then   ' Compare the numeric letter values, and if smaller than user input...
        sht.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete   ' Delete the row
    End If
Next currentRow
```

If you're finding that it's only deleting one row at a time, my guess is that using `sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to find the last row is the reason because you don't have any data in column A?  If your data is in column H as in your original example, change the `A` to an `H` in the code and you should be fine, or try and find a more reliable way to set your `lastRow` variable value.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! I'll give it a try. However, some things are worth noticing. The letters will not always be sequential. There is some mixture that did not show up in my example, but that's why I think the VLookup is necessary. -- Also, the way I need it to work in the end is to have the rows with the higher letter value and also the ones with the lowest number (compared to the user input) deleted.

Comment: Also, I tried your code, but it only deletes one row per time. So I have to run the code as many times necessary to run the entire table.

Comment: @LeonVFX: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, however, it looks like everything is getting deleted independent from what I input. As an example, I created a series of codes in my sheet and I input: (91S) and everything was deleted. :/

Comment: It seems that if I input only a letter, like (S), it deletes every row that contains a lower valued letter in the column. It that case it works, but as I said: I wish to be able to put a letter and a number: (Ex: 91S), and the code would delete the rows with the higher letter value and also the ones with the lowest number (compared to the user input). Thank you in advance!

Comment: @LeonVFX: Sorry, I misread that you wanted to do a comparison on the letter and the numeric value.  Given the code example in my answer you should be able to get it to do what you want with minor tweaking.  With your user input and your data, use `Left` to get the numeric component and store in a variable, `Right` to get the letter component, use the `VLookup`s on your letters and do the comparisons you need to decide if the data row needs deleting.

Comment: No problem! I actually got some help and solved this! Thank you very much for the help!